# C# Linq Group elements from list and count sum of values

Tags: c#, linq, list, sum, aggregation

i have a List of Lists of objects each containing a string and a float value.

I need to group those elements by the string value (name) and order the groups by the sum of float value.

```
 public class Element
    {

        public string Name;
        public float Value;

        public Element(string name,float value) {

            Name = name;
            Value = value;

        }

    }


    List<List<Element>> elementslist = new List<List<Element>>();

    elementslist.Add(new List<Element>() { new Element("Apple", 1.2f), new Element("Banana", 0) });
    elementslist.Add(new List<Element>() { new Element("Apple", 2.1f), new Element("Banana", 1.4f) });
    elementslist.Add(new List<Element>() { new Element("Apple", 0), new Element("Banana", 0) });
```

p.s.: is there any smarter aggregation algorythm to obtain thise result ? Maybe could be also considered of "close" these values are in List order...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a `IEnumerable<Element>` with one element by name and the sum of `Values` in the `Value` member. Hope it helps.

```
elementslist.SelectMany(n => n).GroupBy(n => n.Name).Select(n => new Element(n.First().Name, n.Sum(p => p.Value))).OrderBy(n => n.Value)
```

- Or OrderByDescending.

Answer (score 1):

First flat (`SelectMany`) the list, then `GroupBy` by name and `OrderBy` by `Sum` of values:

```
var groups = elements.SelectMany(l => l)
                     .GroupBy(e => e.Name)
                     .OrderBy(g => g.Sum(x => x.Value))
```

Comment: Might as well add a `.Select(x => new { Name = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(y => y.Value) })` for the output.

Comment: @clarkitect: Yes, I thought it but it is not clear from the question  and as it says that it wants to order the groups I left it in groups.

Comment: Thank you, i needed a bit of syntax about sum :)
-clarkitect thank you for the addon
-Arturo, you were right abot grouping , how to access then the enumerable in order to have the second result ?

Comment: @MirkoArcese: Your welcome, if the answer help you please consider it as accepted.

Comment: Sure it is a valid answer, how to read the name and value of one element in this ordered list ? need a cast ?

Comment: `groups` is an `IEnumerable<IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Element>>`, you can call `ToList` if you want to materialize it in a `List`, each element of this enumerable is a group (an enumerable plus a `Key` property). You can iterate over the groups, then iterate over elements in the group.